# When I can split my dataset into training and validation set before PCA or after PCA?

Tags: python, validation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I want to split my dataset to training and validation sets I don't know whether I should split the dataset before applying pca dimensionality reduction or after pca to avoid leakage of data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset should split before applying PCA to avoid leakage of data